# fix WordPress custom menu character encoding

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The problem is only with custom menus. When I create a new menu and I use non latin letters in menu name such as Arabic menu name or french name with characters such as "é" then it displays bogus characters such as "MunicipalitÃ©Ã©" instead of "Municipalité"

The weird thing is that there are no issues if I add a new PAGE or POST through the wordpress CMS. This issue only happens when adding a new menu.

the entries are being saved wrong in the dabatase too (i checked the mysql database with phpmyadmin, and I saw that the values there have weird characters too).

So I believe this has to do with the database connection but however I do use the following code to specify the CHARSET in wp-config.php which contains the connection string to the database:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I have been fighting with this problem over the last 24 hours. Appreciate any help
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Do you actually mean the menu name, or are you talking about the text of the individual items? Do you have any plugins enabled that change _anything_ about how menus are output by default, does your theme define its own custom nav walker, or something like that? Does the problem persist if you disable _all_ plugins and switch to the default theme, and then try to create a new menu item?

Comment: I am talking about the text of the individual items. I have qTranslate-X plugin enabled to translate the pages. I tried to change theme to twenty seventeen (default wordpress theme) and then I disabled all plugins and then I created a new menu but I still get the same issue. check screenshot I attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not weird at all. wp_editor adds auto html entities. so your accents and such are converted to html entities, thus displayed properly. Menus are a different story, and are saved as is. with enconding being an issue, some installs may have difficulties as yours. try commenting out these 2 lines from the wp_config.php file

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

if this does not succeed, validate your database's character encoding. (simple trick if you have phpmyadmin is to manually insert those characters and validate they are saved properly.

let me know if you still have issues after this!

step 2: (edit 1)
uncomment lines from step 1, and make sure Settings->Reading->Encoding for Pages and Feeds is set to utf-8. make sure your set/collation for your mysql database is set to 
UTF-8/utf8_general_ci
if not, convert all tables. a plugin used to exist for this but i haven't used it in ages and it seems to be unmaintained for an equal period of time... though slight modifications to the routines to make sure data structure is well represented would take less time than manually doing this.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/utf-8-db-converter/
let me know if step 2 fails.

to manually alter tables,

Change tables:

```
ALTER TABLE $table DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Change columns:

```
ALTER TABLE $table CHANGE $field_name $field_name $field_type CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

but as stated., it,s probably simpler to just use the plugin (modify it to suit new wordpress data structure, but then again, i believe it will take you less time than manually going through all existing fields in all existing tables. Changing database default encoding will only affect new tables and new columns

edit 3: issue was solved by using

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

in the wp_config.php file. (troubleshooting happened in chat)

Comment: I did try to comment out these 2 lines already but it did not solve the issue.
I also tried to manually insert those characters into the database through phpmyadmin and they were saved properly

Comment: then they are most likely sanitized my wordpress through a utf-8_encode somewhere before insert. have you tried patching this by using html entities directly? i know it sucks purple camel balls but it would allow clean display 'till we find the issue.. encoding issues can be tedious and long to find.

Comment: using html entities works fine... but as you said, this is very annoying to use as the website is huge and have 2 languages that contain non Latin characters...

Comment: try step 2 :) sry it took so long to write.

Comment: oh and make sure to remove html entities once all tables converted if needed

Comment: I tried step2. notes below:
1- there is no such option to set it to UTF8 in Settings->Reading->Encoding
2- my set/collation for mysql DB was set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci
I changed it to utf8_general_ci and then I tried to create new menus but the issue was still there :(

Comment: you need to alter tables for all tables and columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162998/discussion-between-ralph-thomas-hopper-and-toofast).